# iOS memory warning case crash with error "message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Pushing my view controller twice to navigation controller and simulating memory warning, lead to application crash with error: "message sent to deallocated instance"

I'm pushing view controller by pressing on button:

```
-(void)buttonPressed
{
    MyViewCOntroller *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

- I'm using ARC.

Scenario:

1. `[self buttonPressed];`
2. Press back button in vc.
3. `[self buttonPressed];`
4. Press back button in vc
5. Simulate memory warning

The crash does not happen if pushing only once.

I tried also to move "vc" to be ivar of parent controller, but the effect is the same...

Maybe this will help, but I'm using custom back button and its selector:

```
-(void)backButtonPressed
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Enable zombie, and debug it

Comment: Did that already. It points to "buttonPressed" method. This is how I found the place. But I can't understand the reason and how to handle it.

Comment: Try pushing with segue

Comment: are you trying to access the parent vc from MyViewCOntroller?

Comment: push any view controller before viewDid appear will also cause to crash in iOS7 can you tell me same problem occur if you wait for a while when push view in second time?

Comment: It may occur due to the rapid Push and pop of the controllers, make sure you are not retaining any reference to any object of the controller...

Comment: try to add Symbolic breakpoint with symbol - [YourClass buttonPressed]   more info about Symbolic breakpoint: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html

Comment: Again you didnt answer to my question. If your MyViewCOntroller access the parentview?

Comment: No. It is not. Also the problem is with sending "memory warning" message to the first instance of the controller which has to be deallocated but some how system sends a message to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this. Please see my answer to my other question:

[[UINavigationController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126567/uinavigationcontroller-retain-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance/25139204#25139204)

Answer (score 0):

create this vc object as class member and check if crash exists

```
 @interface ParentViewController()
 {
    MyViewCOntroller *vc;
 }
 @end

 @implementation PaintingViewController


  -(void)buttonPressed
  {
     vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
  }
```

Comment: you mean to make it static?

Comment: try with moving  vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init]; to viewDidLoad